# How to get list of members belonging to specific group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables

- Groups table

### [image: groups table]

- Group Types

### [image: group_types table]

- Users table

  ### [image: users table]
- group_users table

  ### [image: group_users]

I want to get the all details of group (i.e. group members, group types in a single sql query using joins)

> SAMPLE JSON OUTPUT FOR GROUP ID 2

```
{
group_name : second,
group_type:private,
members_list : john , ben
}
```

I had written the following sql join but I haven't reached my goal.!!

```
select uls.name "username", gls.name "group name",gtp.name "group type",gus.status
from user_list uls, group_list gls, group_type gtp, group_users gus
where
uls.user_id=gus.user_id and
gls.group_id=gus.group_id and
gtp.type_id=gls.type_id and
gus.status='active' 
group by gls.name
```

**How can I achieve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [group_concat() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get the list of members into a single field. I would also use explicit join and full group by:

```
select group_concat(uls.name) "username", gls.name "group name",gtp.name "group type",gus.status
from user_list uls
inner join group_list gls
inner join group_type gtp
inner join group_users gus
on
uls.user_id=gus.user_id and
gls.group_id=gus.group_id and
gtp.type_id=gls.type_id
where gus.status='active' 
group by gls.name, gtp.name, gus.status
```

Comment: i would do the same, but without any of that aggregation stuff

Comment: You can do the aggregation in php as well. It depends on how much formatting you want to do in your db operations.

Comment: Let us assume one more table Friends with user_id and friend_id as fields.
If I would like to count the friends that are subscribed to group,then how can i rewrite the query?

Comment: This is a different question from the original. Pls ask this in its own post.

Comment: I'm a bit more lenient :)

Comment: @shadow Thank you for answer,it worked for me , i will post my second question soon,but first I will try.

Comment: If the answer resolved your question, pls mark it as accepted, so other viewers of this topic will know that the question is closed.

Comment: Hi, @Shadow ,I have added my query at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243813/how-to-get-group-details-along-with-members-details-and-common-friends-present) .Can you help me on this issue?